# Выражение "начат постройкой" - почему так?

Tags: грамотная-речь

При строительстве кораблей и соборов (по крайней мере мне попадалось в этих случаях) вместо "начата постройка корабля (собора)" употребляют "начат постройкой". Аналогично употребляют "закончен постройкой".

Почему так? Откуда взялось это выражение именно в такой форме?
Как все-таки говорить правильно?

Comment: Приведите полное выражение, иначе налицо абсурд. И первое тоже: постройка — завершённое в ходе строительства сооружение.

Comment: Например:
Начат постройкой корвет "Громкий"
Взято отсюда:
http://bmpd.livejournal.com/164575.html

Comment: Еще пример: «город начат постройкой; половина стены из камня, другая — из дерева. Здесь выстроены каменные палаты; в них лежат серебряные и золотые деньги, драгоценности и соболя…» Взято отсюда: Бочаров Г. Н., Выголов П. В., Вологда. Кириллов. Ферапонтово. Белозерск, 1977

Comment: Еще пример по ссылке: https://books.google.ru/books?id=dhYoBwAAQBAJ&pg=PT234&lpg=PT234&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=GbJVDGcrHk&sig=Cw1nf33_KOF-XaLd3TO9Rf3aOZE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjFi4qv7brQAhVHjiwKHcfOCJcQ6AEIRTAJ#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false

Answer (score 2):

Так не говорят, но сравнительно часто пишут в исторических *книгах* (включая современные) и мемуарах. Пока прямого разбора выражения не попадается, предположение о его происхождении можно сделать на основании характерных случаев употребления. **"Корабль начат постройкой в таком-то году и закончен вооружением в таком-то".** Здесь просматривается мысль, что военный корабль мало построить (хотя это и важный законченный этап в его *создании*): *построенное* судно нужно ещё и соответствующим образом оснастить, чтобы оно стало самим собой и могло использоваться по назначению. Вероятно, и с храмом то же: сначала он строится в архитектурном смысле, затем в нём появляются иконы и роспись. Трудно сказать, "заканчивается" на этом создание храма (по аналогии с кораблём) или к его дальнейшему существованию относят практику богослужений (ведь и "церковь" - не только архитектурное понятие). Вероятно, в какой-то момент выражение стали относить к городам и другим сущностям, для которых *постройку* можно рассматривать как один из этапов *существования*. Ещё это выражение встречается в мемуарах Молотова, причём речь идёт о некоем большом прессе на заводе (начат постройкой с участием такого-то проектировщика) - его не сразу можно было запустить: перед этим стали сооружать систему служебных трубопроводов и т. п.

Comment: Ну, определенная логика в этом есть. Спасибо. Подождем еще версий.

Answer (score 1):

"Начат постройкой" - термин, употребляющийся вместо термина"заложен". Понятие закладки к настоящему времени  утратило смысл. При Петре Великом это было торжественным актом - первый дубовый брус киля выставлялся на стапель. Перед 1-й мировой это тоже еще имело смысл - первый двутавр киля выставлялся на стапель, далее шпангоуты, обшивка, как при Екатерине, спуск, после чего пустой корпус начинали грузить - котлы, машины, зашивка палуб и т.д. После введения в практику кораблестроения плоскостных, а затем объемных секций закладка перестала быть значимым событием, сохранив в основном ритуальное значение. О какой закладке может идти речь, если на стапель кранами выставляется готовый отсек (скажем, носовое МКО) с котлами, ГТЗА, насосами, собранными палубами и пр. А второй отсек уже на подходе согласно графику постройки. Поэтому более правильно оперировать именно понятием "начат постройкой" - заготовка металла для корпуса, механизмов, вооружения (они ведь зачастую были готовы еще до начала корпусных работ, в случае строительства серии). Классический пример - американские линкоры типа "Montana" - ни один из 5 кораблей не был "заложен", но 2 из них были "начаты".

Т.е. "начат постройкой" - и есть начат - началась сборка корпуса.

А закончится или нет - вопрос. Вот,например, фраза: "Для полноты картины... потом необходимо будет коснуться кораблей, начатых постройкой в войну и законченных уже после нее" Начали собирать, но не окончили.

Это же относится и к городу, собору и прочему, всему, что характеризуется сложной технологией. Раньше город строили как? Камень - символ заложили, на его месте котлован, стены, крыша, окна -первый дом построили. А сейчас? Застраивается сразу целая площадка. Дом собирается из секций. Где-то, конечно, старым методом, но там термином "начат постройкой" и не пользуются, там говорят "заложен".

Comment: Следуя этой логике, термин "закончен постройкой" означает что госкомиссия подписала акт сдачи-приемки, но по факту работы будут продолжаться неопределенное время?

Comment: Возможно.  "Закончен постройкой" вообще не встречала. Сдаётся, речь о том,что фактически строительство окончено, но в эксплуатацию объект не введён. Что-то не готово, может, нет инфраструктуры или не подведены системы какие-то.

Comment: примеры: 
http://starosti.ru/article.php?id=31689
http://bmpd.livejournal.com/33812.html
https://books.google.ru/books?id=aMr7AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA538&lpg=PA538&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&source=bl&ots=wCvPjNj_j1&sig=Xat_jvcQGpRBYxBonFHbjVsXiII&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjmjK6K577QAhVIWiwKHZBsAJMQ6AEIKjAD#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9&f=false

Comment: Видимо есть какое-то общее правило о котором мы не знаем...